# How can I mock a RestTemplateBuilder call to external API in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito, junit5

I'm facing a problem when testing a service (A) which calls a service (B) which calls a service (C) where this last one has the RestTemplateBuilder call.

And the last one is calling directly to the endpoint and I get this error:
`404 Not Found: [no body]`

I will share an example of code:

```
public List<AAAAA> serviceA(long code, long anotherCode){
         return serviceB.getList();
. . . 
}
```

```
public List<BBBB> serviceB(){
     return serviceC.getList();
}
```

```
public List<CCCC> serviceC(){
         RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = restTemplateBuilder
             .basicAuthentication("username","password")
             .build()
             .exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST,HttpEntity, String.class);

    return mapResponseToObject(entity);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

And I'm using this in tests:

```
 given(serviceB(code, anothercode)).willReturn(list);
 given(serviceC).willReturn(list);
```

But it still makes the real call and I don't know what can I do.

Comment: Please, show your whole test code (especially the mocks creation and injection).